# IntelliJIDEA can't find Tomcat Lib directory

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, intellij-idea

I have configured already the Tomcat Server settings in IntelliJ IDEA, but same problem occurs every execution of the program. It prompts an error that `"(AppPath)\build.xml:85 C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\lib does not exist."` (Which is not existing). But I have updated the Home Directory of my Tomcat Server Directory.

See attached images of Configuration and errors below:
[image: Tomcat Configuration]

[image: Error in Building]

Line 85 of build.xml:

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<!--This is Line 84, next is 85th-->
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Can someone help me why this happen?

Comment: where is ${appserver.lib} defined? command line? environment variable?

Comment: I found it already. Ant properties were declared on a `build.properties` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Ant properties were configured in a build.properties file. I modified the `appserver.home` Ant property for building the Spring app, and it works like a charm!